# tablesorter addParser only on initial load

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I'm using a parser on my table sorter and I'm using it to set the order of my table when it is first displayed. The issue is once my table is displayed I want to ignore the parser and use the default sorting options to allow the user to sort the table. Is this possible? if so how do I do it? Here is my tablesorter addParer code: $.tablesorter.addParser({

```
  //give an id to the parser
  id: 'campaigns',
  is: function(s) {
    return false;
  },
  format: function(s) {
    //remove any numbers and spaces in the string s
    var state = s.replace(/[0-9]/g, '').replace(/\s/g, '');
    //change inactive to a 1 and active to a 2
    //only want this to apply on load otherwise after the table has loaded
    //I don't want this to be used. I just want to ignore it
    return state.toLowerCase().replace(/inactive/,1).replace(/active/,2);
  },
  //sort on a numeric type
  type: 'numeric'
});

$(function() {
  $("table#game-data-table").tablesorter({
    //sort based off of active inactive, then off column 4,and finally off column 1
    sortList: [[1,1], [3,1], [0,0]],
    headers: {
    1: {
      sorter: 'campaigns'
    }
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want. But I think if you want a specific order upon initialization, you should set up the HTML with that specific order and not include an initial sort.